# Adding Libxml2 to an Android project under Cocos2D-X

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am having problems porting Libxml2. I like it because it works under windows like a charm with `<libxml/parser.h>`. When I reference the libraries I just cannot find the right path to them, their own references are broken and I don't know how to fiddle with Android.mk

What is the procedure?